# How to extend a simple module from inet?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I get lots of errors like "redeclared" and "class wasn't registered" when I try to extend a simple module from inet. Is it even possible to extend modules outside the inet.src directory?

MyMac.ned

```cc
package myproject.linklayer;

import inet.linklayer.contract.IMACProtocol;
import inet.linklayer.base.MACProtocolBase;

simple MyMac extends MACProtocolBase like IMACProtocol
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=block/rxtx");
        @class(MyMac);
}
```

MyMac.h

```cc
#ifndef __INET_MYMAC_H
#define __INET_MYMAC_H

#include "inet/linklayer/base/MACProtocolBase.h"
#include "inet/linklayer/contract/IMACProtocol.h"

using namespace inet;

namespace inet { } // namespace inet

class INET_API MyMac : public MACProtocolBase, public IMACProtocol
{
    public:
        MyMac();
        virtual ~MyMac();

        virtual void initialize(int stage) override;
};

#endif /* __INET_MYMAC_H */
```

MyMac.cc

```cc
#include "MyMac.h"

using namespace inet;

namespace inet {} // namespace inet

Define_Module(MyMac);

MyMac::MyMac() {}

MyMac::~MyMac() {}

void MyMac::initialize(int stage)
{
    MACProtocolBase::initialize(stage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to prepare a project outside `INET` directory. You should:

1. Create a new `OMNeT++` project, then go to its properties and select `inet` project as `Project References`.
2. Move your files `MyMac.ned`, `MyMac.h`, and `MyMac.cc` into the new project.
3. Modify your `C++` files: the code has to be **inside** the namespace `inet`, all inherited pure virtual methods have to be overridden in your code, `INET_API` may be removed.
4. In `NED` file add a namespace for the C++ class.

Corrected code:
MyMac.h:

```
#ifndef __INET_MYMAC_H
#define __INET_MYMAC_H

#include "inet/linklayer/base/MACProtocolBase.h"
#include "inet/linklayer/contract/IMACProtocol.h"
namespace inet {

class MyMac : public MACProtocolBase, public IMACProtocol
{
    public:
        MyMac();
        virtual ~MyMac();
        virtual void initialize(int stage) override;
    protected:
        virtual void handleUpperPacket(cPacket *packet) override ;
        virtual void handleLowerPacket(cPacket *packet) override;
        virtual bool isUpperMessage(cMessage *message) override;
        virtual bool isLowerMessage(cMessage *message) override ;
        virtual InterfaceEntry *createInterfaceEntry() override;
};
} // namespace inet
#endif /* __INET_MYMAC_H */
```

MyMac.cc:

```
#include "MyMac.h"
namespace inet {

Define_Module(MyMac);
MyMac::MyMac() {
}

MyMac::~MyMac() {
}

void MyMac::initialize(int stage) {
    MACProtocolBase::initialize(stage);
}

void MyMac::handleUpperPacket(cPacket *packet) {

}
void MyMac::handleLowerPacket(cPacket *packet) {
}

bool MyMac::isUpperMessage(cMessage *message) {
}

bool MyMac::isLowerMessage(cMessage *message) {
}

InterfaceEntry *MyMac::createInterfaceEntry() {
}

} // namespace inet
```

MyMac.ned:

```
package myproject.linklayer;

import inet.linklayer.contract.IMACProtocol;
import inet.linklayer.base.MACProtocolBase;

simple MyMac extends MACProtocolBase like IMACProtocol
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=block/rxtx");
        @class(inet::MyMac);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In MyMac.cc I still get 2 errors:
Define_Module(MyMac); // undefined reference to `_imp___ZTIN4inet5MyMacE'"
MyMac::MyMac() { // 'inet::MyMac::MyMac' redeclared without 'dllimport' attribute: previous 'dllimport' ignored [-Winconsistent-dllimport] and undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN4inet5MyMacE'

Comment: Remove `INET_API` from class declaration, and add a namespace into a class in `NED` file, then clean and rebuild your project. I have updated my answer.