# What to do when AdhocHost in the Inet call a function similar to a handlemessage when they receive message or packet?

Tags: omnet++

I require an approach that whenever the one of host nodes in the following NED scenario receives a message or packet, a function like handlemessage is called. I want to extend a simple or compound module from AdhocHost in the Inet, for example, called Txc1 with all AdhocHost properties. Is it even possible to extend this mentioned simple module outside the Inet directories and subdirectories?
How can I reach this goal? How to code it in NED file, h, and cc files of this module?

My NED file for the network is as:

```
import inet.environment.common.PhysicalEnvironment;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.AdhocHost;
import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211DimensionalRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.integrated.IntegratedVisualizer;

network Net80211
{
    parameters:
        int numHosts;
        @display("bgb=600,400;bgi=background/terrain");
        @signal[packetSent](type=inet::Packet);
        @signal[packetReceived](type=inet::Packet);
        @statistic[packetSent](title="packets sent"; source=packetSent; record=count,"sum(packetBytes)","vector(packetBytes)"; interpolationmode=none);
        @statistic[packetReceived](title="packets received"; source=packetReceived; record=count,"sum(packetBytes)","vector(packetBytes)"; interpolationmode=none);
        @statistic[throughput](title="throughput"; unit=bps; source="throughput(packetReceived)"; record=vector);
        @signal[reqStreamBytes](type=long);
        @statistic[reqStreamBytes](title="requested stream bytes"; record=count,sum,vector; interpolationmode=none);
        @statistic[rcvdPkLifetime](title="received packet lifetime"; source="dataAge(packetReceived)"; unit=s; record=stats,vector; interpolationmode=none);
        @statistic[rcvdPkSeqNo](title="received packet sequence number"; source="appPkSeqNo(packetReceived)"; record=vector; interpolationmode=none);
    submodules:
        visualizer: IntegratedVisualizer {
            parameters:
                @display("p=640,15;is=s");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                @display("p=640,112;is=s");
        }
        radioMedium: Ieee80211DimensionalRadioMedium {
            parameters:
                @display("p=638,56;is=s");
        }
        host[numHosts]: AdhocHost {
            parameters:
                @display("r=,,#707070;p=300,200;is=s");
        }
        stModule: StModule {
            @display("p=639,169;i=block/cogwheel;is=s");
        }
        globalListener: GlobalListener {
            @display("p=67,128");
        }
}
```

Notes:

1. stModule is a simple module, for writing results in the finish function.
2. As an approach, if a new module extends from AdhocHost and it is able to trigger its own handlemessage function, it is replaced instead of AdhocHost.
3. As my rule, that function should be defined at the network layer. It is better to have a similar function in the data link layer, too.
4. A similar and simple question is in [A new module that inherit from AdhocHost in omnet++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734211/a-new-module-that-inherit-from-adhochost-in-omnet). Although I test this approach, it has a problem(not call handlemessage).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392495/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392495/how-to-extend-a-simple-module-from-inet/38425588#38425588).

Comment: Dear @JerzyD, I looked at your approach, but in my case, because of inheriting AdhocNode, I think I must inherited from a class or glasses that be related to AdhocNode, in declaration of new class. What changes are needed?

Comment: You have written "I want to extend a simple module from AdhocHost" but it is impossible to extend **simple** module from a compound module. Moreover, AdHocHost is a compound module that contains physical layer, network layer, transport layer, application layer etc. Which module from AdHocHost do you want to extend? Could you provide more details about your intention as well as version of INET and OMNeT++ you use?

Comment: I edited the question for more clarity. I use Omnet 5.6.1 and Inet 4.2. I need to handle the handlemessage function for the AdhocNode (in this question, host) in stModule module (stModule.cc). in other words, I require an approach when a host node receives a message/packet, the hadlemessage is called in stModule for collectiong all information of packets received by host nodes in stModule module.

Comment: Could you edit your question and describe stModule - what it represents, how it is build etc. The sentence "*handle the handlemessage function for the AdhocNode ... in stModule module*" is incomprehensible to me. What is more, every host (node) consists of many modules (i.e., physical layer, data link layer, network layer, ...). In every layer there is handleMessage() method. Could you precise which layer you are considering when you write *node receives a message/packet*"?

Comment: Dear @JerzyD., I edited the question according to your notes.